# Pug Error Handling for a NodeJS, Express and Pug based Application

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, pug

I'm using Node.js, Express and Pug to create a simple Webserver.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "command-line-args": "^4.0.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "less-middleware": "~2.2.0",
    "merge": "^1.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.1",
    "tracer": "^0.8.9"
  }
}
```

The server is started with the start command:

```
npm start
```

When the app contains errors like calling a non existing pug mixin:

```
.container
    +hossa
```

an error text is rendered and shows up in the client browser like so:

```
/Projects/.../status.pug:2 1| .container > 2| +hossa 3| 4| 5| div.page.container.hidden#status(text="Status") pug_mixins.hossa is not a function
```

which is ok, but could be improved.

The main problem: I see no error in the log output other than a 500 code.

The questions are:

- what code, modul, and/or startup options are needed to log the error including the full stack information on the server side?
- How do I manage it to render some more user friendly message?

Comment: You must use [**error handler**](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Aikon Mogwai commented - I simply forgot to add a proper error handler.

Something like this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    // very basic!
    console.error(err.stack);

    // show user some message - for Ajax requests which expects a specific format
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ok: false, message: err.message}));


    // OR

    // more advanced:
    // check error type, context etc. and act accordingly
    // - log message
    // - send appropriaty error page etc.
    // - eventually use next handler
    // - set res.status
    // sth. like this

    if (req.xhr) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' });
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
});
```